# Good resources for parsing excel files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm going to start taking an excel file for a bulk member upload in my ASP.Net C# Web application.

Does anyone know of any good free libraries for parsing excel sheets or where I can find good documentation for parsing excel files?

There's only going to be one sheet in the workbook... I'm just looking for something to get me started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/).

It's simple and easy to use. Supports Excel 97 through 2007.

Comment: I used this. You're right it is simple to use, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Access Database Engine redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=ja&displaylang=en), and parse Excel files via ADO.NET.

Even though it's for "Access", it allows parsing of .xls and .xlsx files, as well.  See the documentation on that page for connection string details.